# How to install additional libraries in jupyterhub on AWS EMR?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I want to install additional libraries in my `jupyterhub` for Python3 kernel. I am using EMR release `emr-5.23.0` with only `jupyterhub` installed. The [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html) states a certain method called `bootstrap actions` and I am using it. My cluster gets created without any trouble but I cannot see the libraries installed.

I have tried several permutations and combinations and read several articles, none differ from what the official documentation states.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker exec jupyter bash -c "yes | python3 -m pip install nltk"
```

I expect this library to get installed but instead, I am seeing no module error in my notebooks.

Comment: @PV8 Did you read my question? At what point did you notice that this could be a duplicate?

Comment: I overread the amazon part

Comment: That does not make sense, if you had overread the amazon part, you would understand that this question is different. Do you mean _ignored_ the amazon emr part?

Also, do you agree that this question is not a duplicate?